# How do I echo the session name in a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, session, foreach, echo

I am looping through my session variables. I have been able to echo the session values, but I would also like to echo the session name that corresponds with that value.

How do I echo out the session variable name each time it loops?

This is the code I currently have:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $value) {
    echo  'Current session variable is: ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: If it is just for debugging purposes, it is faster to use print_r($_SESSION, true);

Comment: I'd second `print_r()` - not only does it accomplish the same, it also has much nicer formatting (and gives an indication of types).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Would I put the print_r($_SESSION, true); inside of the foreach loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This?

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    echo  'Current session variable ' . $key . ' is: ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: no problem at all. the other answers probably got more details and you might want to read them as well.

Answer (score 3):

With a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, you can get both keys' names, and the corresponding values, using this syntax :

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
    // Use $key for the name, and $value for the value
}
```

So, in your case :

```
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    echo  'Current session variable is: ' . $value . ' ; the name is ' . $name . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop allows to specify a variable for a key. Simply use `$var => $val` where `$val` is the variable holding the index and `$val` is the variable holding the value.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    echo  'Session variable ' . $key . ' is: ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v) 
{
   echo 'Variable ' . $k . ' is ' . $v . '<br />' 
}
```